# Нужно считывать лог по telnet при постоянном соединении

Tags: php, сокет, telnet

PHP. Нужно подключиться к железке по telnet и получить от нее лог действий.

Вопрос в том, что при удачной авторизации выводится список событий с последнего коннекта и далее telnet не рубит соединение — при новых событиях дополняет лог новыми строками на экране по мере их происхождения.
[image: вид лога]
Мне нужно подключаться, собирать всю информацию про произошедшим событиям и отключаться (и так раз в 5 минут).

Танцы с socket_recv() приводят к зависанию скрипта на получении данных.

Каким образом можно обнаружить что данные уже получены и остановить получение?

Comment: А зачем отключаться ? виси себе и дочитывай сразу как данные появятся. это же удобнее, чем постоянно переподключатся. А вообще http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-set-blocking.php

Comment: В случае выключения АТС, разрыва соединения с железкой или еще какого либо события. Т.е. я не могу быть уверен что если коннект висит в телнете, он еще физически существует.

Comment: В общем делайте свой сокет неблокирующим и читайте до возникновения ошибки или данных нулевой длины

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше воспользоваться готовым классом https://github.com/ngharo/Random-PHP-Classes/blob/master/Telnet.class.php

p.s. А у железки нет SNMP ?

Comment: нет, только такой вариант. Это АТС и раньше так подключались принтеры и печатали логи.

Класс пробовал, но не смог добиться корректной работы в виду той самой специфики задачи